# Jquery using comslider doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using a website call comslider to create a image slider for my website. It works great in Firefox, but is not recognized in IE.

Here is the code for the image slider directly from the site:

```
<div>
    <div id="comslider_in_point_64128">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oCOMScript64128 = document.createElement('script');
    oCOMScript64128.src = "http://www.comslider.com/target/users/1382722700x5c3a788e540f63519d170cdf03cdd76f/comslider.js?timestamp=1382724173";
    oCOMScript64128.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(oCOMScript64128);
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery 2.x it only works in IE 9+.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Just as an FYI, Questions posted here usually require some minimal level of effort and understanding on behalf of the asker.  Dumping a bunch of code and simply saying it doesn't work is generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

comSlider service has been updated. It works now with IE7+. Some fallbacks to simple effect are added for effects which are supported only on new browsers (e.g. HTML5, canvas, ...)